# Верстка, расположить 2 элемента в строку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Требуется сделать вот такую вот форму, но у меня никак не получается расположить `input` на одной строке с `div`, в котором текст.

Блок, который на скриншоте в длину имеет фиксированную ширину: `300px`

[image: .]

**Код:**

```css
input {
  padding-left: 7px;
  border: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2 !important;
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  color: #1f191a;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
}

.login-inputs-wrap {
  width: 300px
}

.login-input,
.password-input {
  width: auto;
  color: #1f191a;
}

.login-input-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1f191a;
}

.password-input-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1f191a;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.login-title,
.password-title {
  float: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-inputs-wrap">
  <div class="login-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="login-input" type="text" name="login" value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="login-title">login</div>
  </div>
  <div class="password-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="password-input" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo @$data['password']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="password-title" style="">password</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код ваших неудачных попыток прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @kizoso добавил, пробовал и с flex, с ним работает только если, width не 300px, а 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный вид можно реализовать используя placeholder для input и псевдоклассы для него.

Или абсолютно позиционированный блок с текстом, но в таком варианте придется прятать текст при фокусе и заполненности поля, привел вариант при помощи css, но он не очень корректный, лучше это делать на js. Плюс данного варианта, что можно скрывать плейсхолдер с эффектом анимации, но если этого не требуется, лучше воспользоваться первым вариантом.

```css
.only-input::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  text-align:right;
}
.only-input:-moz-placeholder{
  text-align:right;
}


.input-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-row {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}

.input-row + .input-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.input-row input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
}

.input-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.input-row > input:focus + .input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.input-row > input:valid + .input-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="login" class="only-input">
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="only-input">
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="text" required>
    <span class="input-placeholder">login</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-row">
    <input type="password" required>
    <span class="input-placeholder">password</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline-block` дочерним элементам

```css
.login-input-wrap>*,
.password-input-wrap>* {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%
}

.login-input-wrap,
.password-input-wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 300px
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none; // не рекомендуется
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="login-inputs-wrap">
  <div class="login-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="login-input" type="text" name="login" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="login-title text-right">login</div>
  </div>
  <div class="password-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="password-input" type="password" name="password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="password-title text-right" style="">password</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

На флексах

```css
.login-input-wrap,
.password-input-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 300px
}

input {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none; // не рекомендуется
}
```

```html
<div class="login-inputs-wrap">
  <div class="login-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="login-input" type="text" name="login" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="login-title">login</div>
  </div>
  <div class="password-input-wrap">
    <div>
      <input class="password-input" type="password" name="password" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="password-title" style="">password</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, только я добивался, что бы текст был привязан справа

Comment: Сделал, но если flex не проблема сейчас кину на них

Comment: Добавил, но вообще такое пишется через input + label, второй при активности  инпута позицианируется по желанию, вверх в сторону итп